# Overriding an internal method (reflection, emitting)

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, reflection.emit, internals

I want to create the following class:

```
    public class MultiDataOrTrigger : DataTrigger
    {
        public MultiDataOrTrigger()
        {

        }

        // evaluate the current state of the trigger
        internal override bool GetCurrentState(DependencyObject container, UncommonField<HybridDictionary[]> dataField)
        {
            bool retVal = false;

            for (int i = 0; !retVal && i < TriggerConditions.Length; i++)
            {
                retVal = TriggerConditions[i].ConvertAndMatch(StyleHelper.GetDataTriggerValue(dataField, container, TriggerConditions[i].Binding));
            }

            return retVal;
        }
    }
```

How to call internal methods, create instances of internal types - I more or less figured it out. For this, the use of reflection is enough for me.

But I still can't figure it out myself with overriding the virtual internal method specified in another assembly.

### Update

In response to comments:

I understand this can be solved without such a class - I understand that there are many other solutions or workarounds. I myself use many of these in practice. I have not stopped any development right now due to the fact that I do not know how to solve this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure you can override an internal method. Messing around with internals of other classes feels a bit janky though. Can't you just create your own wrapper class instead?

Comment: Can.
And in some recent topic it was done.
But I would like to override MultiDataTrigger.
In XAML, it was much easier to use it than a wrapper implementation.

Comment: I understand there are many workarounds.
Therefore, I wrote that there is no urgent need for this.
But there is a desire to understand and learn new things.

Comment: I don't think you can. If your code is in a different assembly then it doesn't qualify as internal.

Comment: I've seen a solution with Reflection.Emit creating a dynamic type.
On Sharpe it can be used.
But for XAML, it doesn't occur to me how it can be used.

Answer (score 5):

If this is what you *really* want to do, then yes, it *is* possible to override an internal method in another assembly using reflection emit.

If you read the [CLI specification (ECMA-335)](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf) (in particular, section II.10.3.3, "Accessibility and overriding"), you will find this:

> [Note: A method can be overridden even if it might not be accessed by the derived class.
>
> If a method has assembly accessibility, then it shall have public accessibility if it is being overridden by a method in a different assembly. A similar rule applies to famandassem, where also famorassem is allowed outside the assembly. In both cases assembly or famandassem, respectively, can be used inside the same assembly. end note]

(Here, `assembly`, `famandassem` and `famorassem` correspond to C# `internal`, `protected private` and `protected internal`, respectively.)

But there is a catch. In the same section, you will also find:

> If the strict flag (§II.23.1.10) is specified then only accessible virtual methods can be overridden.

The C# compiler sets this flag on all non-public virtual methods. So you cannot extend a class from a C# compiled assembly and override an internal method declared in that assembly, even with reflection emit, unless you are able to remove the strict flag from that method (perhaps using a binary editor, and if the assembly is strong named then this will invalidate the signature). But you *can* create two assemblies with reflection emit, define a base class with a virtual internal method in the first one, and extend the class and override the method in the second assembly, which can be demonstrated with this code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

public interface IBase {
    void X();
}

class Program {
    
    public static void Main() {
        ILGenerator ilGenerator;

        var assembly1 = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(
            new AssemblyName("EmittedAssembly1"),
            AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run
        );

        var module1 = assembly1.DefineDynamicModule("EmittedModule1");

        // Define the base class.
        var typeBuilderBase = module1.DefineType("Base", TypeAttributes.Public);
        typeBuilderBase.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);
        typeBuilderBase.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(IBase));

        // This is the internal method that will be overridden.
        var methodBuilderBaseX = typeBuilderBase.DefineMethod(
            "X",
            MethodAttributes.Assembly | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.NewSlot,
            typeof(void),
            Array.Empty<Type>()
        );

        ilGenerator = methodBuilderBaseX.GetILGenerator();
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "X from Base");
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new[] {typeof(string)}));
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        // Define an explicit interface implementation that will be used to call
        // Base.X() from the created instance of Derived.
        var methodBuilderBaseInterfaceX = typeBuilderBase.DefineMethod(
            "IBase.X",
            MethodAttributes.Private | MethodAttributes.Virtual,
            typeof(void),
            Array.Empty<Type>()
        );

        ilGenerator = methodBuilderBaseInterfaceX.GetILGenerator();
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, methodBuilderBaseX);
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        typeBuilderBase.DefineMethodOverride(methodBuilderBaseInterfaceX, typeof(IBase).GetMethod("X"));

        typeBuilderBase.CreateType();

        // This is the assembly in which the internal method will be overridden.
        var assembly2 = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(
            new AssemblyName("EmittedAssembly2"),
            AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run
        );
        var module2 = assembly2.DefineDynamicModule("EmittedModule2");
        
        var typeBuilderDerived = module2.DefineType("Derived", TypeAttributes.Public);
        typeBuilderDerived.SetParent(typeBuilderBase);
        typeBuilderDerived.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);

        // Override the internal method in Base. Note that the accessibility of the overridden
        // method must be public.
        var methodBuilderDerivedX = typeBuilderDerived.DefineMethod(
            "X",
            MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual,
            typeof(void),
            Array.Empty<Type>()
        );

        ilGenerator = methodBuilderDerivedX.GetILGenerator();
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "X from Derived");
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new[] {typeof(string)}));
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var typeDerived = typeBuilderDerived.CreateType();

        // Create an instance of the emitted Derived type.
        var instance = (IBase)typeDerived.GetConstructor(Array.Empty<Type>()).Invoke(Array.Empty<object>());

        // Call the overridden method. This outputs "X from Derived"!
        instance.X();
    }

}
```

If you add `MethodAttributes.CheckAccessOnOverride` (which is the `strict` flag) to the definition of `X` in `Base`, you will get this error (which is the same as what you would get when attempting to do this with a C# compiled type):

> Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Method 'X' on type 'Derived' from assembly 'EmittedAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is overriding a method that is not visible from that assembly.

Comment: I started to study Emit, but one moment confused me.
As a result of all these actions, I will get a dynamic type.
On Sharpe, I can still contact him.
But how do I use it in XAML?
The XAML needs a real type from a real assembly.